# C# 10 nullable type "?" character display seems inconsistent in the Intellisense display of the XML documentation

Tags: c#, intellisense, nullable, xml-documentation, nullable-reference-types

Consider the following code snippet:

```
/// <summary>
/// Serializes this <see cref="ICollection"/>? object to a <see cref="string?"/>, skipping nulls.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="val">The value to process.</param>
/// <param name="separator">Optional separator.</param>
/// <returns><see cref="string?"/>.</returns>
public static string? SerializeToString(this ICollection? val, string? separator = null)
{
    if (val is null)
        return null;
```

With reference to the XML documentation, with `cref="ICollection?"/>`, Intellisense will not display the `?`, which is why I put it after the `<see />` block.

However, with `<see cref="string?"/>`, it will display the `?`.

`<see cref="MatchCollection?"/>` won't display the `?`.

Two of these examples are classes, one is an interface.

I noticed the `?` won't display with generics, such as `public A[]? MyFunc()`.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Would `Nullable{MatchCollection}` and `public Nullable{A[]} MyFunc()` work in the short term?

Comment: I'm sure they would. I'm just trying to wrap my mind around what is happening. I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm misunderstanding some fundamental.

Comment: It definitely seems to me like an oversight when implementing nullable reference types. (Or rather, when updating XML document generation to support NRTs).

Comment: `string?` will be displayed, but you cannot click it.